# Avoiding N+1 selects in Grails / Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, grails, orm

**UPDATE**: May be related to this Grails bug in 2.0.1:
http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.groovy.grails.user/125400

**UPDATE 2**: This gets me the closest but the pagination does not work.  In this case, all A's are returned, each with their list of B's and each B with its C.  As soon as I add offset and max, things get messed up.  For instance, in this case, 10 A's will not be returned.  Perhaps 1 A and 9 B's will be returned.

```
def results = A.list([fetch:[bees: "eager"], offset: 0, max: 10]);
```

---

Problem: I want to load all A's, their associated B's and B's associated C in one query.  Retrieving all A's and their associated B's in one query is very simple.  I'm not sure how to also load all B's C as part of the same single query. By design, the default mapping from B -> C should be eager since I will always want C when I load B.  I thought setting this mapping would solve the problem.

```
class A {
    static hasMany = [
            bees:  B,
    ]
}

class B {
    C c;

    static belongsTo = [a: A]

    // also tried this and every possible combination
    //static fetchMode = [c: 'eager']

    static mapping = {
        c fetch: 'join'
        // c lazy: 'false'
    }
}

class C {
    String someField;
}
```

Here's my query:

```
def results = A.executeQuery("from A a left join fetch a.bees",
                     [max: pageSize, offset: offset]);
```

If I now iterate over the results:

```
for (A a in results) {
   for (B b in a.bees) {
      println "B: " + b; // this is OK, B is already loaded
      println "B's C: " + b.c.someField; // C not loaded
   }
}
```

When I iterate over results, the line b.c.someField will cause a "select" to be executed per each B.  This is bad I want to avoid this if possible.  I posted a solution as an answer that uses a second query with a lookup map but there must be a better way.

The query I posted in "Update 2" gets me very close.  In fact it works fine until I use pagination (with offset/max).  The Grails user guide mentions that "fetch: 'join' may cause issues with queries with a offset/max but it does not go into any detail.  Note: In order for this query to work I had to disable hibernate query cache as mentioned in "Update 1" due to a bug in Grails 2.0.1.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried doing it without going the `.executeQuery()` route and instead just used the built-in GORM methods and object-graph traversal? Something like `A.bees.each {/* do stuff with a.b.c */}`

Comment: def bees = B.list(fetch:[c: "eager"]);  <-- This seems to work specifically for getting all B's with c loaded.  But it's not exactly what I want.

Comment: Updated my question to include the fetchMode which also doesn't seem to work.

Comment: two things: a.) If this is the bug you linked to, then that's the answer: "it's a bug". Otherwise, b.) what is it exactly that you want? Thus far, the two pieces of "get the bees" code you have shared do two different things.

Comment: The bug is one part.  By disabling hibernate query cache, now B.list() and B.findAll() will honor the mapping in B and eagerly load C.  That was not the original question though, but without solving this much more basic problem I had no hope in finding the answer for the more complicated problem I posted.

Comment: Please see the edit I posted Update 2.  I gets me close to the solution.  In fact it works if I want to retrieve ALL A's, but I wanted A's to be paginated.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to simply fetch all A's and their associated B's.

Once you have that, you can get all C's ID's without doing any query:

```
def cIds = [] as Set;

for (A a : results) {
    for (B b : a.bees) {
        // Note: getCId() is a special method which does not cause a query
        cIds.add(b.getCId());
    }
}
```

Once you have all of the C ID's you can fetch these from the database with a second query and store them into a map for lookup later:

```
def cMap = [:]
def cees = C.getAll(cIds.toList());
for (C c : cees) {
    cMap[c.id] = c;
}
```

And now, you can iterate over the original result set to print out C's fields:

```
for (A a : results) {
    for (B b : a.bees) {
        println "The meaning of life is " + cMap[b.getCId()].someField;
    }
}
```

Total queries = 2 (one for the original left join, and a second to get all C's)

If someone has a better solution please post.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of Grails, GORM does lazy loading by default. Hereis the link to the document http://grails.org/doc/1.1/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20(GORM).html

I'm not clear as to what you are asking here

Comment: I want to load all A's, their associated B's and B's associated C in one query.  It's dead simple in plain SQL - a simple 3 way join across 3 tables.

Comment: I tried to update the original question to make it more clear.